# Selenium Chrome node: Test Application Charts not loaded on Chrome node

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest, selenium-grid

I am testing a trading application. When I run on my local machine, the application along with charts (e.g. Market Data charts) are loaded correctly.

However, when I run it on a Selenium Chrome node the charts are not loaded it just displays a blank area.
I am running on a docker locally using Hub-Node. The same behavior with Firefox as well.

The charts are JS charts.

Any pointers how I could resolve this problem?

Thank you!

Tried running locally, it works but not on chrome node.